# VarHandle to Java Foreign Memory Segment without bounds checking in Java 21

Tags: java, memory, java-21, varhandle, java-ffm

I'm trying to update from Java 17 to 21, but I have problems with `VarHandle`s from `java.lang.foreign`. I obtain `VarHandle` to the memory segment using

`VarHandle varhandle = layout.varHandle(path)`

But this method includes bounds checking on SequenceLayouts and IndexOutOfBounds exception.
Other than that, I need the same behaviour as in Java 17.

How do I turn it off?

UPD:
I need the method to work for any SequenceLayout

For example:

```
var innerLayout = MemoryLayout.structLayout(
  MemoryLayout.sequenceLayout(5, ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG).withName("a"),
  ValueLayout.JAVA_INT.withName("b"),
)

var layout = MemoryLayout.structLayout(
  MemoryLayout.sequenceLayout(n, innerLayout).withName("x"),
  MemoryLayout.sequenceLayout(m, innerLayout).withName("y"),
)

var xVarHandle = layout
  .varHandle(PathElement.groupElement("x"), PathElement.sequenceElement(), PathElement.groupElement("a"), PathElement.sequenceElement())

var yVarHandle = layout
  .varHandle(PathElement.groupElement("y"), PathElement.sequenceElement(), PathElement.groupElement("a"), PathElement.sequenceElement())
```

Comment: Can’t you just create a SequenceLayout with an element count that is Long.MAX_VALUE?  There is even a [method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/foreign/MemoryLayout.html#sequenceLayout(java.lang.foreign.MemoryLayout)) for that.

Comment: The answer depends on the memory layout and layout path you're using. But, it's not possible to completely 'turn off' bounds checking

Comment: @JornVernee I meant for any SequenceLayout. Updated the question, added a clarifying example

Comment: @JornVernee In profiling I can see that I have performance issues because of bounds checking via a call to Invokers.checkCustomized

Comment: If you're seeing a call to `checkCustomized` using a sampling profiler, then it looks like the VarHandle is not being optimized away. Make sure your VarHandle instances are constants, for instance by storing them in `static final` fields and using from there. This also requires the memory layout to be statically known. If the layout you're using is not statically known, you're probably better off manually computing the access offsets, and then using MemorySegment::get/set instead.

Comment: @JornVernee Does "statically known layout" mean that all of the offsets and layout size are known at compile-time? Or are just the offsets enough?

Comment: Essentially yes, or more precisely: since the layout is needed to create the var handle, you need to know the dimensions of your sequence layouts (`n` and `m`) at least by the time you're initializing the `static final` fields with those var handles.

Answer (score 1):

You're stuck in an XY problem; "turning off bounds checking" is not a thing.  What is probably happening is that your VH calls are not being inlined, probably because of reasons such as those outlined by Jorn's comment:

> If you're seeing a call to checkCustomized using a sampling profiler, then it looks like the VarHandle is not being optimized away. Make sure your VarHandle instances are constants, for instance by storing them in static final fields and using from there.